# CDS data for different industries/rating?

Tags: market-data, bloomberg, cds

I have come across below `CDS` data (index values) based on different Rating, Industries, and Regions,

[image]

I am wondering where can I get more complete data i.e. such data for all different rating categories etc. current as well as historical time series.

Does `Bloomberg` offer similar kind of data?

Any insight is highly helpful

Comment: What do these figures 0.65%, 0.47% represent? CDS spreads?

Comment: @DimitriVulis most probably yes